# Wait for all API request call on input method in textbox, Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am calling an API to validate number exist or not in our database. I am calling the method on (input) event of textbox which will call the API. Now If I type in input box '1234' then there will be four API calls made, first for '1', second for '12', third for '123', fourth for '1234'. Now if '123' does not exist in database API will return 'true' and button will be enabled, If '1234' exist in database, API will return 'false' and button will be disabled. The issue is for some split seconds the button will be enabled as '123' was true and in the textbox it is '1234' as API call for the fourth request is still pending. So button will be enabled for '1234' and this value in textbox will be used in further process which we don't want. Any better way how to handle this type of case?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the concept of [Debouncing](https://blog.bitsrc.io/3-ways-to-debounce-http-requests-in-angular-c407eb165ada#:%7E:text=Debouncing%20is%20the%20delay%20of,when%20the%20specified%20has%20elapsed.). It delays the execution of a method(HTTP call in your case) for a certain period of time.

Another approach can be using `debounceTime` and `switchMap` RxJs operators.

Comment: His problem with the delay, he needs an immediate interactivity, so how would you recommend him Debouncing

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle it immediately you have to go with [Web Socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

It's like the `typing...` in chat applications, you show it as long as user is typing on his device's keyboard

On the other hand, and while you are sending http request you have to wait for server to resolve your request.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, System has to provide suggestions to user while user
typing. Sending request for each and every request to server will be
overhead. So sending request to server when user finishes typing will
give good performance. We can detect whether user typing or finished
his typing by delaying the change event.

```
      <input (ngModelChange)="displayName()" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
      import { Component } from '@angular/core';
      import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

         @Component({
         selector: 'my-app',
          template: `
           <h4>Type something in below text box</h4>
           <input (ngModelChange)="displayName()" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
           <h4>Value : {{name1}} </h4>
          `
        })
        export class AppComponent {
           name: string = '';
           name1: string = '';
           _timeout: any = null;

           constructor(public lc: NgZone) {

           }

           displayName() {
             this._timeout  = null;
             if(this._timeout){ //if there is already a timeout in process cancel it
               window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
             }
             this._timeout = window.setTimeout(() => {
                this._timeout = null;
                this.lc.run(() => this.name1 = this.name);
             },1000);
          }
        }
```

Comment: this is an ugly way to do it. Better to use rxjs